# Obtain SSH Session results from Switch

Tags: bash, centos7

I am trying to obtain all of the MAC data from a switch using a Bash script on a CentOS7 system. Here is my current attempt:

```
#!/bin/bash

somefunc11 () {
sshpass -p XXXXXX ssh -c aes128-cbc -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 -tt cisco@XXXXIPXXXXX <<-'EOF' 
        terminal datadump
        show mac address-table vlan 300
EOF
}

(somefunc11 > sshlog) & sleep 5 ; kill $!
```

This script works just fine in /home/myuser
but fails in /usr/src/script.sh

Error message: /script.sh: line 12: kill: (38315) - No such process

Comment: Why don't you add `exit` or something similar as command in your here-document to close the connection cleanly?

Comment: `& pid=$! ; sleep 5 ; kill "$pid"` maybe.

Comment: Both options did not work, but I appreciate the suggestions. Thank you.